# Tkinter Widget For Loop is typing in every Widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried creating a widget for loop that would only allow one letter input, but I'm running into an issue where it creates text for every widget. I assume the issue lies with the "len" I used.

```
from tkinter import *
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
root = Tk()

height = 6
width = 5

delta=0

entries = []

def limitSizeDay(*args):
    value = dayValue.get()
    if len(value) > 1: dayValue.set(value[:1])

dayValue = StringVar()
dayValue.trace('w', limitSizeDay)




for i in range(height): #Rows
  newrow = []
  for j in range(width): #Columns
    b = Entry(root, text="",width=2,font=('Arial', 40, 'bold'), textvariable=dayValue)
    b.grid(row=i, column=j)
    newrow.append(b)
  entries.append(newrow)


def getword(event):
    global b
    ass = b.get()
    print(ass)
    keyboard = Controller()
    keyboard.press(Key.tab)
    keyboard.release(Key.tab)

root.bind('<Return>', getword)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The problem is that you have bound every `Entry` box to the same textvariable (`dayValue`).  When you change that one variable, all of the boxes respond.  I can't tell what you are really trying to achieve with this.  If you want each box to have its own variable, then you need to create a LIST of `StringVars`, probably inside the loop so you get the same size.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim said the cause of your problem is binding the same `StringVar` to all of the `Entry` widgets. To make this work, you need to create a `StringVar` for each `Entry` in a loop:

```
for i in range(height): #Rows
  newrow = []
  for j in range(width): #Columns
    dayValue = StringVar()
    dayValue.trace('w', limitSizeDay)
    b = Entry(root, text="",width=2,font=('Arial', 40, 'bold'), textvariable=dayValue)
    b.var = dayValue # Prevent garbage collection (I think)
    b.grid(row=i, column=j)
    newrow.append(b)
  entries.append(newrow)
```

Then you need to change `limitSizeDay` to access the variable.

```
def limitSizeDay(var, *args):
    value = root.globalgetvar(var)
    if len(value) > 1: root.globalsetvar(var, value[:1])
```

The `globalgetvar` and `globalsetvar` methods allow you to get and set the variable respectively as the usual `getvar` and `setvar` don't work in this case.